# SharePoint and Boostrap in Content Editor WebPart

Tags: css

I normal do webparts based in `Content Editor` -> using url to `.html` file. Works very well.

Now I need to add in html a reference for boostrap CSS file. The big question is, the boostrap css file will overwrite SharePoint CSS styles, so some SharePoint features crash.

Any one know a workaround? I don´t want to use full boostrap in SharePoint site, because I want to design people change color font size etc, throw SharePoint theme editor.

Thanks

Comment: Have you visited this link? You can get some reference of using bootstrap with SharePoint 2013 form here http://sharepointificate.blogspot.in/2015/02/bootstrap-responsive-framework-with.html

Comment: not bad post! not bad! but there is any better post out there?

Comment: you can override the css, use same (original) CSS from SharePoint and include it after your bootstrap css reference.

Answer (score 1):

This link help me:

http://sharepointificate.blogspot.pt/2015/02/bootstrap-responsive-framework-with.html

Another way is include again sharepoint masterpage css again in html file.